# SQL Server Database Project: Get Visual Studio Assembly Version on Pre-Deploy Scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlcmd

I want to know the current version of the visual studio project assembly version from VS settings before I deploy my database to the target. Is there any way to get the version in T-SQL SQL-CMD command to decide what action is needed to take?

Comment: After identifying are you planning to change the target? It is not possible because you need to build by setting database project into target environment

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking about the DB compatibility level, not the server version? You can query sys.databases for your DB name as follows.

```
select 
  name, compatibility_level , version_name = 
    CASE compatibility_level
        WHEN 80  THEN 'SQL 2000'
        WHEN 90  THEN 'SQL 2005'
        WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL 2008'
        WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL 2012'
        WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL 2014'
    END
from sys.databases
```

Comment: No, by version, I meant the assembly version of the visual studio project which we set in the project properties. I want to know what is the current assembly number in the SQL-CMD scripts.